# Changing color of body report, depending on value in table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have report in SQL Server 2008.

Report has a parameter, parameter values:

```
organization1
organization2
organization3
organization4
```

To display a list of parameter with values, I used "Available Values" "Get values from a query".

[image: Parameter]

- If value of organization1 parameter in "Value" column is greater than
  20, then report body and background of tables should be in red color.
- If selected parameter organization1 background of tables and report body should be in red color.
- If selected parameter organization2 background of tables and report body  should not be in red color.
- If selected parameter organization3 background of tables  and report body  should be in red color.
- If selected parameter organization4 background of tables and report body  should not be in red color.

[image: Ugliest report ever created by man]

The expression below does not work for selected parameter.

```
=IIF(Fields!AVID.Value, "summ_work">20 and
First(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value, "test")="Organization1","Red","Transparent")
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need something like this for the `BackGround` expression in the report.

```
=Switch(Sum(Fields!value.Value, "DataSet1") > 20 And Parameters!Organization.Value = "Organization1", "Red",
    Parameters!Organization.Value = "Organization1", "Red",
    Parameters!Organization.Value = "Organization2", "White",
    Parameters!Organization.Value = "Organization3", "Red",
    Parameters!Organization.Value = "Organization4", "White",
    True, "Yellow")
```

That last line of the `Switch` is a catch all that will turn the background Yellow. Do what you want with that, or remove it entirely if you don't think the situation will happen where someone passes a parameter value other than what you have in the list.

I went with White as the "should not be in red" color, change that to something else if you like.